# module 'google.protobuf.internal.containers' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, spacy, gensim

My workplace has decided to introduce two factor authentication (2FA) and all of a sudden none of my project work as they did before. I have no idea if this 2FA is actually causing the problem but as simple task as: "import spacy" doesn't work any more. I get this lengthy error message:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import spacy

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py:11, in <module>
      8 setup_default_warnings()  # noqa: E402
     10 # These are imported as part of the API
---> 11 from thinc.api import prefer_gpu, require_gpu, require_cpu  # noqa: F401
     12 from thinc.api import Config
     14 from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\api.py:2, in <module>
      1 from .config import Config, registry, ConfigValidationError
----> 2 from .initializers import normal_init, uniform_init, glorot_uniform_init, zero_init
      3 from .initializers import configure_normal_init
      4 from .loss import CategoricalCrossentropy, L2Distance, CosineDistance

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\initializers.py:4, in <module>
      1 from typing import Callable, cast
      2 import numpy
----> 4 from .backends import Ops
      5 from .config import registry
      6 from .types import FloatsXd, Shape

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\backends\__init__.py:7, in <module>
      4 from contextvars import ContextVar
      5 import threading
----> 7 from .ops import Ops
      8 from .cupy_ops import CupyOps, has_cupy
      9 from .numpy_ops import NumpyOps

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\backends\ops.py:11, in <module>
      9 from ..types import FloatsXd, Ints1d, Ints2d, Ints3d, Ints4d, IntsXd, _Floats
     10 from ..types import DeviceTypes, Generator, Padded, Batchable, SizedGenerator
---> 11 from ..util import get_array_module, is_xp_array, to_numpy
     14 ArrayT = TypeVar("ArrayT", bound=ArrayXd)
     15 FloatsT = TypeVar("FloatsT", bound=_Floats)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\util.py:38, in <module>
     35     has_torch_gpu = False
     37 try:  # pragma: no cover
---> 38     import tensorflow.experimental.dlpack
     39     import tensorflow as tf
     41     has_tensorflow = True

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:41, in <module>
     38 import six as _six
     39 import sys as _sys
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     44 # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py:40, in <module>
     31 import traceback
     33 # We aim to keep this file minimal and ideally remove completely.
     34 # If you are adding a new file with @tf_export decorators,
     35 # import it in modules_with_exports.py instead.
     36 
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     43 
     44 # Bring in subpackages.
     45 from tensorflow.python import data

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py:32, in <module>
     29 import numpy as np
     30 import six
---> 32 from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\function_pb2.py:7, in <module>
      5 import sys
      6 _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
----> 7 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
      8 from google.protobuf import message as _message
      9 from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py:47, in <module>
     45   import binascii
     46   import os
---> 47   from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
     48   _USE_C_DESCRIPTORS = True
     51 class Error(Exception):

AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.internal.containers' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing spacy again, I have tried pip installing protobuf, I have tried this:

```
import collections.abc
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
```

as advised on one of the posts here, I have checked that I have the same versions as my colleague and remote machine(for whom it works on his laptop but not on remote), I have tried upgrading python (from 3.8.8 to 3.8.12)  - nothing seem to work. There are additional problems like same problem with gensim as with spacy, or one project imports everything successfully but produces now errors for me, while it was working before 2FA. Can anybody share any ideas of what could be causing this and how can I fix it? We don't even know how to direct IT with where the issue is - they don't know anything about python and I'm not sure if the issue is with python? Can anybody please help me to understand what is happening?

Comment: It's unlkely the cause is related to any 2FA adoption. From an issue at <https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9180> it looks like it may be a versioning/configuration issue with recent relevant Google pacakges - & downgrading your protocolbuffers package(s), if possible, *might* be a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the version of protobuf you have installed, and degrading to 3.17.3 or some lower version.
That worked for me.